# C# How to apply row filter after refresh dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh, rowfilter

I can save the current dataGridView scroll and focus position but it doesn't work when I apply a filter. How can I apply the row filter or keep the selected row after refresh datagridview?

```
public void button_refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
        int col = (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
        int scroll = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select * from PPAPdatabase";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                "Important Note",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);             
        this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[col, row];
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scroll;
    }
```

Filter:

```
private void text_Pnumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Part Number] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Pnumber.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You keep the reference to indexes that have no meaning if you change the underlying data. What was before at row index 10 could be at row index 0 when you change the filter because the first 9 row are excluded by the filter.

Comment: @Steve yes, that's my problem. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have an unique value in your DataTable (like an ID autoincrement)?. You should try to read that value as your bookmark, then after the filter search the grid for that value and if you find it mark the row as the current one.